# Plotting a function defined by a series in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am wondering how I would go about plotting a function in python, given a function f(x) defined by the series:

cos(x)/1 - cos(3x)/3 + cos(5x)/5 - cos(7x)/7 + ...

here was my initial approach:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, .01)
def cos_series(input,n):
    func=np.zeros(n)
    count = 0
    while count<n:
        func[count]=4/np.pi*(np.cos((2*count + 1)*input)/(2*count + 1))
        count+=1
    return func


plt.plot(x,cos_series(x,20))
plt.show()
```

where input would be my x-values and n determines how many cosine terms the series would contain. This does not work though, and returns the error:

```
    func[count]=4/np.pi*(np.cos((2*count + 1)input)/(2count + 1))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Anybody know what I should do?

Comment: First thought with your code.  Never define a variable with a python builin named function.  input is a python function, so that could be the cause of your problem.  What output do you get from the function cos_series?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because func is a 1d array, and the term:

```
4/np.pi*(np.cos((2*count + 1)*input)/(2*count + 1))
```

is in itself a 1d array with all the f values for the different arrays. This means you are trying to set an array element with another array, hence the error message.

Since you also need to add all your terms of f(x) and the term above is already an array I would suggest doing the addition/subtraction in your loop

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, .01)
def cos_series(x,n):
    f=0
    count = 0
    while count<n: 
        f+=((-1)**count)*(4/np.pi*(np.cos((2*count + 1)*x)/(2*count + 1)))
        count+=1
    return f


plt.plot(x,cos_series(x,20))
plt.show()
```

Also not that I change the variables func and input, these are builtin python names and it is not good practice to use them.

Comment: Thanks guys! After playing around with it a bit (and changing the func and index variable names), I ended up using two while loops, one to repeatedly add the cosine terms, and one to assign the sum to an index of my function.